# How to access a dictionary from __init__ another class in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following problem. I try access dictionary content, but i getting error KeyError: 'testDatast'. 
I declare dictionary in SampleApp. In the StartPage class, create the 'test' key with a value of 6.
How can I get access to this key in Next class? Inside __init__method?
In this case, the 'testData' key is located default value for Scale widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font  as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.discUserInfo = {}
        self.frames = {}


        for F in (StartPage, Next):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.cursor= self.controller.cursor
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Login", font=controller.title_font)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Login:")
    label2.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
    label2.place(x=310, y=90, in_=self)
    self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
    self.e1.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
    self.e1.place(x=370, y=90, in_=self)
    label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Pass:")
    label3.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
    label3.place(x=310, y=120, in_=self)
    self.e2 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
    self.e2.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)
    self.e2.place(x=370, y=120, in_=self)
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                        command=self._login_btn_clicked,width = 25)
    button1.pack()
    button1.place(x=310, y=150, in_=self)

def _login_btn_clicked(self):
    username = self.e1.get()
    password = self.e2.get()
    hash = hashlib.sha512()
    hash.update(('%s%s' % ('salt', password)).encode('utf-8'))
    password_hash = hash.hexdigest()
    sql = "Select COUNT(id) AS count, email,id,name from users Where username = %s AND password = %s"
    self.cursor.execute(sql, (username,password_hash))
    daneUsera = self.cursor.fetchall()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    srtdata = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    fromData = srtdata + ' 00:00:00'
    toData = srtdata + ' 23:59:59'
    sql2 = "Select row1,row2,row3 from user_data Where userId = %s and day between %s and %s"
    self.cursor.execute(sql2, (daneUsera[0]['id'], fromData, toData))
    daneUsera2 = self.cursor.fetchall()

    if daneUsera[0]['count'] > 0:
        self.controller.discUserInfo['name'] = daneUsera[0]['name']
        self.controller.discUserInfo['userId'] = daneUsera[0]['id']
        self.controller.discUserInfo['data'] = daneUsera2
        self.controller.show_frame("Next")
    else:
         tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")

class Next(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Next", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        buttonAudio = tk.Button(self, text="xx",
                                command=self.ttt, width=20)
        buttonAudio.pack()
        w = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=8, orient='horizontal')
        w.pack()
        w.set(self.controller.discUserInfo['data']['row1'])
    def ttt(self):
        print(self.controller.discUserInfo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 650))
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I strongly encourage you to _not_ use this architecture (the concept of pages and a controller). It wasn't designed for beginners. I recommend starting with a single frame that has your login, and then you can destroy that frame and create the others once the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

You run `Next.__init__` which uses `self.controller.discUserInfo['testData']` before you set it in `StartPage._login_btn_clicked`. Set default value in `StartPage.__init__`

Comment: But in StartPage._login_btn_clicked authorization takes place. And there discUserInfo['testData'] value is taken from the database. unless we do not understand each other :(

Comment: I can't really see the difference in where you get your value from. You try to use it before it's set. `self.controller.discUserInfo['testData'] = 6` looks like an assignmen to me and not a database read. In the same way `w.set(self.controller.discUserInfo['testData'])` reads from a variable, not a database. If that is any clearer...  Could you use `show_frame()` to update the value of `w`?

Comment: I do not know how :( i added entire StartPage class

Comment: Well, now it doesn't work at all because: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'cursor' .

Comment: I'm going to have to go and have a life for a few hours now. Be back later. :)